# email to case subject line

Tags: email2case

We are using two fields called cat1 and cat2 in the case.
While sending an email-to-case with the subject like (cat1*cat2), the system will create a case with those values.
The problem is that when some encrypted data is used in the subject before those values (encrypted data, cat1*cat2), The system is not considering those cat1 and cat2 values while generating the case. Any idea on how to ignore the encrypted data in the subject line and consider the very next cat1 and cat2 values?

Comment: `Case.Subject` is limited to 255 chars so if the encrypted data exceeds that length, `cat1*cat2` will be ignored. see [SFDC Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm?search_text=case)